# Define priority for docker container with restart policy always

Tags: linux, docker

On a Linux server, I've serveral Docker containers running. For example, some Compose-Stacks for Wordpress hosting. But also internal applications like Confluence. After a reboot, it seems that the internal containers were started first. So the hosting containers (like Wordpress) are down for several minutes.

That's not good, since the internal apps were used by a few persons, where the external ones have much more traffic. So I want to define some kind of priority: Like starting the Wordpress containers *before* the Confluence, to name a concret example.

How can this be done? All containers have the restart policy *always*. But it seems not possible to define in which orders the containers should start...

Comment: I doubt there is anything of this kind existing as of now. And I see very limited use cases which may need this, so might not be even in list of docker upcoming releases anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

**version 3+** : Version 3 no longer supports the condition form of running containers.

**version 2** : `depends_on` will help your case if you do `docker-compose up`, but ignores when you run in swarm mode.

`docker-compoopse.yml`  (works after version 1.6.0 and before 2.1)

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
  db:
    image: postgres
```

**DOCS** :

[depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on)

[Controlling startup order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

Comment: `depends_on`seems only to work inside a compose file. But I've different compose files. For example compose file #1 with Jira/MySQL and compose file #2 with nginx/php. `depends_on` seems fine to define dependencies like a application server which should start after a database server in the same app. But not for my problem. Although, I can't understand why this feature was removed in version 3.